# Rank of any submatrix of a Cauchy matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, cauchy-matrices

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359270/besides-vandermonde-matrix-is-there-any-other-m-by-n-mn-matrix-in-which) said that any $n \times n$ submatrix of a $m \times n$ cauchy matrix has full rank, where $m > n$.

Question: Is it possible to generalize the statement into non-sqaure submatrix? That is, any $a \times b$ submatrix of a cauchy matrix has full rank, where $a,b < m$

Comment: Well, given that any submatrix of a Cauchy matrix is a Cauchy matrix … what do you think?

Comment: I think it is possible to generalize the statement. But I don't know whether it is correct because I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: What I said is not restricted to square matrices. The statement you quoted implies that any Cauchy matrix has full rank. There isn't anything more to say.