# n-rows submatrices of a Vandermonde matrix have full rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359270/tall-m-times-n-matrices-whose-submatrices-with-n-rows-have-full-rank), they mentioned that $m\times n$ Vandermonde matrices have the property that any submatrix with $n$ rows has full rank.

Does that mean if the submatrix is $n\times r$, where $r\leq n$, then the submatrix has full column rank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinant of any such submatrix formed by the rows $k_1,k_2,\dots k_n$ is
$$
\prod\limits_{1\le j<i\le n}(x_{k_i}-x_{k_j})
$$
with $x_{k_i}\neq x_{k_j}$ for $i\neq j$, which is obviously non-zero.

Comment: A a confusion here, I thought they meant that any $n\times r$ submatrix has full column rank ($r\leq n$), does this still hold? I will add this to the question.

Comment: Oh, I think the submatrix does have full column rank since all its columns are independent...